# Make an animated sprite finish playing after key action isn't pressed

Tags: animation, 2d, godot

I'm trying to make a muzzle flash for a gun in a 2d game. I have the animation playing when you press and hold the left mouse button. The animation sprite playing the animation disappears after the left mouse button is released. But it looks janky when it disappears mid animation.

```
extends StaticBody2D

@onready var _animated_sprite = $AnimatedSprite2D


func _process(_delta):
    visible = false
    if Input.is_action_pressed("shoot"):
        visible = true
        _animated_sprite.play("muzzleFlash")
    else:
        _animated_sprite.stop()
    look_at(get_global_mouse_position())
    rotation_degrees += 180
```

I haven't really known where to start on fixing it since I'm new to godot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `_process` will run every graphics frame. And it is checking if the action `"shoot"` is pressed. If it is, it plays the animation, if it isn't it stops it... The result is that the first frame when the action is not pressed, the animation will stop...

If you do not stop it, it shall run to the end:

```
extends StaticBody2D

@onready var _animated_sprite = $AnimatedSprite2D


func _process(_delta):
    visible = false
    if Input.is_action_pressed("shoot"):
        visible = true
        _animated_sprite.play("muzzleFlash")

    look_at(get_global_mouse_position())
    rotation_degrees += 180
```

**Note**: Make sure the animation is NOT set to loop.

You might want to make sure the animation restarts, in that case you can stop it before playing:

```
extends StaticBody2D

@onready var _animated_sprite = $AnimatedSprite2D


func _process(_delta):
    visible = false
    if Input.is_action_pressed("shoot"):
        visible = true
        _animated_sprite.stop()
        _animated_sprite.play("muzzleFlash")

    look_at(get_global_mouse_position())
    rotation_degrees += 180
```

And you probably want it to be visible while the animation is playing, you check using `_animated_sprite.is_playing()`:

```
extends StaticBody2D

@onready var _animated_sprite = $AnimatedSprite2D


func _process(_delta):
    visible = _animated_sprite.is_playing()
    if Input.is_action_pressed("shoot"):
        _animated_sprite.stop()
        _animated_sprite.play("muzzleFlash")

    look_at(get_global_mouse_position())
    rotation_degrees += 180
```

You can also use that check in your `if` conditional if you want to avoid restarting the animation. The following is just one way to do it:

```
extends StaticBody2D

@onready var _animated_sprite = $AnimatedSprite2D


func _process(_delta):
    if _animated_sprite.is_playing():
        visible = true
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("shoot"):
        _animated_sprite.play("muzzleFlash")
    else:
        visible = false

    look_at(get_global_mouse_position())
    rotation_degrees += 180
```